# Downloading Javascript File from Website using Python

Tags: javascript, python, download, bioinformatics

I am trying to use python to download the results from the following website:

```
http://david.abcc.ncifcrf.gov/api.jsp?type=GENBANK_ACCESSION&ids=CP000010,CP000125,CP000124,CP000124,CP000124,CP000124&tool=chartReport&annot=KEGG_PATHWAY
```

I was attempting to use mechanize before I realized that the Download File is written in javascript which mechanize does not support. My code so far opens the web page as shown below. I am stuck on how to  access the Download link on the web page in order to save the data onto my machine.

```
import urllib2

def downloadFile():

    url = 'http://david.abcc.ncifcrf.gov/api.jsp?type=GENBANK_ACCESSION&ids=CP000010,CP000125,CP000124,CP000124,CP000124,CP000124&tool=chartReport&annot=KEGG_PATHWAY'
    t = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    s = t.read()
    print s
```

The results that are printed are

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <form name="apiForm" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="rowids">
    <input type="hidden" name="annot">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.apiForm.rowids.value="4791928,3403495,....";   //There are really about 500 values
      document.apiForm.annot.value="48";
      document.apiForm.action = "chartReport.jsp";
      document.apiForm.submit();
    </script>

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody know how I can select and move to the Download File page and save that file to my computer?

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 2):

After some more research on that link, I came up with this. You can definitely use mechanize to do it.

```
import mechanize

def getJSVariableValue(content, variable):
    value_start_index = content.find(variable)
    value_start_index = content.find('"', value_start_index) + 1

    value_end_index = content.find('"', value_start_index)

    value = content[value_start_index:value_end_index]
    return value

def getChartReport(url):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    resp = br.open(url)
    content = resp.read()
    br.select_form(name = 'apiForm')
    br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
    br.form['rowids'] = getJSVariableValue(content, 'document.apiForm.rowids.value')
    br.form['annot'] = getJSVariableValue(content, 'document.apiForm.annot.value')
    br.form.action = 'http://david.abcc.ncifcrf.gov/' + getJSVariableValue(content, 'document.apiForm.action')

    print br.form['rowids']
    print br.form['annot']

    br.submit()

    resp = br.follow_link(text_regex=r'Download File')
    content = resp.read()
    f = open('output.txt', 'w')
    f.write(content)


url = 'http://david.abcc.ncifcrf.gov/api.jsp?type=GENBANK_ACCESSION&ids=CP000010,CP000125,CP000124,CP000124,CP000124,CP000124&tool=chartReport&annot=KEGG_PATHWAY'
chart_output = getChartReport(url)
```

Comment: I have tried versions of this. I receive the error output of:

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    downloadFile()
  File "C:\Python27\DAVIDLink.py", line 14, in downloadFile
    content = br.follow_link(text_regex=r"Download File").read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mechanize.py", line 569, in follow_link
    return self.open(self.click_link(link, **kwds))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mechanize.py", line 553, in click_link
    link = self.find_link(**kwds)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mechanize.py", line 620, in find_link
    raise LinkNotFoundError()
LinkNotFoundError'

Comment: from my understanding this is because mechanize cannot understand or interpret javascript which the website is primarily written in. @Jordan

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I accidentally missed that step when browsing it for myself. I'll see if I can figure something out.

Comment: @Marea ok I edited my answer with an actual working, tested example. That spits out the content to a file named output.txt in the same folder that you run the script from. I'm sure you can modify to suit your needs.